# How to change XLForm disabled row text color [XLFormRowDescriptorTypeText]

Tags: ios, xlform

I have a disabled row:

```
XLFormRowDescriptor *row = ... XLFormRowDescriptorTypeText ...
row.disabled = @YES
```

By default, the disabled row has a gray color, but I need to change its default color.

I tried setting its 'textField.textColor' , but that doesn't work.

My question is, how to change default color?

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

> XLFormRowDescriptor *row = ... XLFormRowDescriptorTypeText ...
>   row.disabled = @YES

```
[row.cellConfigIfDisabled setObject:[UIColor redColor] forKey:@"textLabel.textColor"];
```